# SharePoint calendar CSS is not showing properly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

I'm working on SharePoint calendar it is working fine on another site but its not loading CSS in my project showing the below error in chrome console. Do you guys have any idea how to fix this.

```
Refused to apply style from '/sites/new/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=5' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually there? I've seen this when the url is incorrect. You would think it would give a 404, but instead it says this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing type="text/html" to type="text/css" in the link tag, and it will correct the error.

Comment: Already have text/css tag but nothing happen.